# How to Flip FaceOSC in Processing3.2.1

Tags: opencv, video, canvas, camera, processing

I am new to the Processing and now trying to use FaceOSC. Everything was done already, but it is hard to play the game I made when everything is not a mirror view. So I want to flip the data that FaceOSC sent to processing to create video.

I'm not sure if FaceOSC sent the video because I've tried flip like a video but it doesn't work. I also flipped like a image, and canvas, but still doesn't work. Or may be I did it wrong. Please HELP!

//XXXXXXX// This is some of my code.

```
import oscP5.*;
 import codeanticode.syphon.*;

 OscP5 oscP5;
SyphonClient client;

PGraphics canvas;

boolean found;
PVector[] meshPoints;

void setup() {
size(640, 480, P3D);
frameRate(30);
initMesh();

oscP5 = new OscP5(this, 8338);

// USE THESE 2 EVENTS TO DRAW THE 
 // FULL FACE MESH:
  oscP5.plug(this, "found", "/found");
  oscP5.plug(this, "loadMesh", "/raw");
  // plugin for mouth
  oscP5.plug(this, "mouthWidthReceived", "/gesture/mouth/width");
  oscP5.plug(this, "mouthHeightReceived", "/gesture/mouth/height");
      // initialize the syphon client with the name of the server
  client = new SyphonClient(this, "FaceOSC");
  // prep the PGraphics object to receive the camera image
  canvas = createGraphics(640, 480, P3D);

}

void draw() {  
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
// flip like a vdo here, does not work
     /* pushMatrix(); 
  translate(canvas.width, 0);
  scale(-1,1);
  image(canvas, -canvas.width, 0, width, height);  
  popMatrix(); */

  image(canvas, 0, 0, width, height); 


  if (found) {
    fill(100);
    drawFeature(faceOutline);
    drawFeature(leftEyebrow);
    drawFeature(rightEyebrow);
    drawFeature(nosePart1);   
    drawFeature(nosePart2);           
    drawFeature(leftEye);     
    drawFeature(rightEye);        
    drawFeature(mouthPart1);  
    drawFeature(mouthPart2);  
    drawFeature(mouthPart3);
    drawFeature(mouthPart4);
    drawFeature(mouthPart5);
  }


 }
//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
void drawFeature(int[] featurePointList) {
  for (int i = 0; i < featurePointList.length; i++) {
    PVector meshVertex = meshPoints[featurePointList[i]];
    if (i > 0) {
      PVector prevMeshVertex = meshPoints[featurePointList[i-1]];
 line(meshVertex.x, meshVertex.y, prevMeshVertex.x, prevMeshVertex.y);
}
ellipse(meshVertex.x, meshVertex.y, 3, 3);
  }
}
/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
public void found(int i) {
  // println("found: " + i); // 1 == found, 0 == not found
  found = i == 1;
}
//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: can you please share the links of FaceOSC? I mean the library link?

Comment: You can find that easily with google. And FaceOSC is not a library, it is a kind of open source program.

Answer (score 0):

The `scale()` and `translate()` snippet you're trying to use makes sense, but it looks like you're using it in the wrong place. I'm not sure what canvas should do, but I'm guessing the face features is drawn using `drawFeature()` calls is what you want to mirror. If so, you should do place those calls in between `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` calls, right after the `scale()`.

I would try something like this in draw():

```
void draw() {  
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  //flip horizontal
  pushMatrix(); 
  translate(width, 0);
  scale(-1,1);


  if (found) {
    fill(100);
    drawFeature(faceOutline);
    drawFeature(leftEyebrow);
    drawFeature(rightEyebrow);
    drawFeature(nosePart1);   
    drawFeature(nosePart2);           
    drawFeature(leftEye);     
    drawFeature(rightEye);        
    drawFeature(mouthPart1);  
    drawFeature(mouthPart2);  
    drawFeature(mouthPart3);
    drawFeature(mouthPart4);
    drawFeature(mouthPart5);
  }

  popMatrix();
 }
```

The push/pop matrix calls isolate the coordinate space.
The coordinate system origin(0,0) is the top left corner: this is why everything is translated by the width before scaling x by -1. Because it's not at the centre, simply mirroring won't leave the content in the same place.

For more details checkout the [Processing Transform2D tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/)

Here's a basic example:

```
boolean mirror; 

void setup(){
  size(640,480);
}
void draw(){
  if(mirror){
    pushMatrix();
    //translate, otherwise mirrored content will be off screen (pivot is at top left corner not centre)
    translate(width,0);
    //scale x -= 1 mirror
    scale(-1,1);
    //draw mirrored content
    drawStuff();
    popMatrix();
  }else{
    drawStuff();
  }
}
//this could be be the face preview
void drawStuff(){
  background(0);
  triangle(0,0,width,0,0,height);
  text("press m to toggle mirroring",450,470);
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'm') mirror = !mirror;
}
```

Another option is to mirror each coordinate, but in your case it would be a lot of effort when scale(-1,1) will do the trick. For reference, to mirror the coordinate, you simply need to subtract the current value from the largest value:

```
void setup(){
  size(640,480);
  background(255);
}
void draw(){
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,30,30);
  //subtract current value(mouseX in this case) from the largest value it can have (width in this case)
  ellipse(width-mouseX,mouseY,30,30);
}
```

You can run these examples right here:

```js
var mirror; 

function setup(){
  createCanvas(640,225);
  fill(255);
}
function draw(){
  if(mirror){
    push();
    //translate, otherwise mirrored content will be off screen (pivot is at top left corner not centre)
    translate(width,0);
    //scale x -= 1 mirror
    scale(-1,1);
    //draw mirrored content
    drawStuff();
    pop();
  }else{
    drawStuff();
  }
}
//this could be be the face preview
function drawStuff(){
  background(0);
  triangle(0,0,width,0,0,height);
  text("press m to toggle mirroring",450,470);
}
function keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'M') mirror = !mirror;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(640,225);
  background(0);
  fill(0);
  stroke(255);
}
function draw(){
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,30,30);
  //subtract current value(mouseX in this case) from the largest value it can have (width in this case)
  ellipse(width-mouseX,mouseY,30,30);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```